# android change textview text at unloaded XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 different XML  layout
1 - main layout (at this we select Title)
2 - post overview layout ( at this we see selected Title and post and...)

i want change other XML value when main XML is on my screen

main XML layout name is : main;
2nd XML layout name is : postreader;

when user select title at main layout application change the 2nd layout Title to selected title but i see default value of they Textview ( according to this cod if my database is null i must see "ASdasdasdasd" but i cant see any thing

```
content.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            if (position>0)
            {
                    /*post_title.setText("kar nakard khit shodi");
                    post_text.setText("kar nakard khit shodi");*/
                    String olagh = shomareradif[position];
                    String khar = "'"+olagh+"'";
                try {
                    ResultSet post_data = st.executeQuery("SELECT ID , post_title , post_content , post_status FROM fa_posts WHERE ID='1' ");//"+khar);

                    post_title.setText(post_data.getString("post_title")+"ASdasdasdasd");
                    post_text.setText(post_data.getString("post_content")+"asdasdasdasdasdd");
                    setContentView(R.layout.postreader);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                //  TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

                }
            //  shomareradif[position]

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you want to change the value in the Activity (or fragment) or download a new one with the chosen text?

Comment: hello sorry for my speedly question - i need change in fragment XML layout ( edited my question )

Comment: So you want to load a new layout for the current activity, after the text will be selected?

Comment: i want change text of 2nd layout before i load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you are doing but the reason you are seeing the default value is because you call `setContentView(R.layout.postreader)` which anytime you call that it sets the content to the default `View`s and their values.

Its rarely ever a good idea to call `setContentView()` more than once in an `Activity`, IMHO. It would probably be best to either call an `Activity` who's `layout` has the `TextView`s that you want and send the `String`s to it as `extras` in the `Intent` and set the text that way.

Or, if you don't have many `View`s in either `layout` then you could add them all to the same `layout` and toggle `visibility` in your `onItemClick()` function.

Comment: thanks my textview is on postreader layout ; if i active it to change (my try  has been finished because it work with main layout listview ) so my value dont trace to changing ------ if i change textview befor active postreader (when contentview is main ) i get error and my app will be close  ### is way to i work on one XML multy layout ( i turn off firsl full layer and turn on 2nd layer ) i think it is not bad way

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you are saying. What "layers" are you "turning off"?

Comment: thanks sorry my english is too bad > when i raed your answer again i got what you say thanks thanks thanks (trhiple thanks :P )

Comment: No problem, sorry I wasn't able to understand you that well. Keep working on your Android and your English and you'll be fine.